# Magnetic field in two conducting parallel plates. (stripline)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetostatics

Studying Poynting Vector power density I found a geometry that I really can't figure it out and is nowhere to be found on the internet.

I have two conducting parallel plates with opposite surface current density but they are joined to be a ring. How would I go about getting its magnetic field? or inductance, I'm trying to later calculate the total magnetic energy but can't see how to set the Maxwell equations in differential or integral forms for getting the magnetic field

Io is given and it assumes  $h \ll b-a$; $h\ll a$; $h\ll b$
[image]

the total magnetic energy is: [image]

I tried using boundary conditions, I think the field must be on the $z$ direction, but I think I need to make some assumptions about the dimensions to solve it and can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the current is flowing CCW around the shaded upper surface and CW around the lower surface, then the resultant B field is coming in from the sides and exiting through the holes (with a zero at the geometric center).  You can consider that each surface carries a series of circular current loops each of radius (r) and width (dr).  Then each segment  of each loop contributes to the B field at each point in the vicinity of the apparatus (and beyond).  If you know a formula for the field energy of a single circular loop of current, one might add those (by integration) to get a total for your configuration.  Finding the energy by finding the field at sample points would be a challenge.

Comment: It occurs to me that the work required to bring single loops together would complicate the energy calculation.